# jsonobject does not fully encapsulated a jsonarray or an arraylist when conveting

Tags: java, android

I am trying to sync contacts from the phone to the server using a `sync adapter`, when I retrieve a list of the contact from the phone and convert it into a `jsonobject`, the jsonobject does not fully encapsulated or contains the entire list. For example if the list size is 820 the jsonobject only contains 245 phone number and when I print out the jsonobject it does not have closing brackets, e.g {contacts :["07034355","0534535", just ends prematurely.
Please help me to find the solution.

1. 1.Whats wrong
2. How to fix it.
3. if its an item within the list that does not match a json format how do I detect it
4. whats the best practice to sync contacts

Here is my code:

```
public void sync_contacts(Context context)
{

     mContext=context;
    mContentRevolver=context.getContentResolver();
    phone.clear();
    util = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
    String code=GetCountryZipCode();
    Log.d(TAG,"COuntry ID:"+code);
    if (mContentRevolver!=null){
         phone=getAllContacts(mContentRevolver,code);
        if (phone!=null){
            String server_ip=mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.server_ip_url);
            String file=mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.contact_sync);
            String url=server_ip+file;
            JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(phone);
            Log.d(TAG,"Array size"+jsonArray.length());

            String arrayListPhone=jsonArray.toString();
           Log.d(TAG,"Json Array to string"+arrayListPhone);
            //Log.d(TAG,"Array size"+arrayListPhone);
           // Log.d(TAG,"array list: "+arrayListPhone);
          /*  String phonenumber=PhoneNumber.getPhone();
            if (phone!=null && url!=null){
                Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<>();
                map.put("phone",phonenumber);
                map.put("contact_array",arrayListPhone);
                send_data_via_volley(map, url, new Contact_Volley_CallBack() {
                    @Override
                    public void Respond(String respond) {
                       Log.d(TAG,"Respond: "+respond);
                    }
                });

            }*/
        }

    }




}

public String GetCountryZipCode(){

    String[] countries=new String[3];
    String CountryID="";
    String CountryZipCode="";
    String CountryName="";

    TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    //getNetworkCountryIso
    CountryID= manager.getSimCountryIso().toUpperCase();
    String[] rl=mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.CountryCodes);
    for(int i=0;i<rl.length;i++){
        String[] g=rl[i].split(",");
        if(g[1].trim().equals(CountryID.trim())){
            CountryZipCode=g[0];
            break;
        }
    }

    return CountryZipCode;
}
private void validate_phone(String number){

}
public ArrayList<String> getAllContacts(ContentResolver contentResolver,String country_code){
    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
JsonArray jsonArray=new JsonArray();
    ArrayList<String> phone = new ArrayList<>();
    String copywith0 = null;
    Phonenumber.PhoneNumber number;
    ContentResolver cR=contentResolver;
    Cursor cursor=cR.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
    if ((cursor!=null ? cursor.getCount() : 0)>0){
        int i=0;
        boolean isValid;
        while (cursor!=null && cursor.moveToNext()){
            String id=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))>0){
                Cursor cursorPhone=cR.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID+"=?",
                        new String[]{id},null);
                while (cursorPhone.moveToNext()){

                    String s=cursorPhone.getString(cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    s=s.replace(" ","");

                    //s=s.replace("+","");
                    copywith0=s;
                    if (s.startsWith("0")) {
                        s = s.replaceFirst("0*","+"+country_code);
                    }
                    if (isValidMobileNumber(s)) {
                        s=s.replace("+","");


                        phone.add(convertStandardJSONString(s));
                           // phone.add(s);

                       // Log.d(TAG,"Phone: valide phone "+s);
                    }else {
                        //Log.d(TAG,"Phone: invalide phone "+copywith0);
                        if (copywith0.startsWith("0")){
                          //  Log.d(TAG,"Phone: valide phone stating with 0 "+copywith0);
                            for (String r:util.getSupportedRegions()){
                                try {
                                    if (util.isPossibleNumber(copywith0,r)){

                                        number = util.parse(copywith0, r);

                                        // check if it's a valid number for the given region
                                        util.isValidNumberForRegion(number, r);
                                        if (util.isValidNumberForRegion(number, r)){
                                            copywith0=copywith0.replaceFirst("0*",String.valueOf(number.getCountryCode()));
                                            if (isValidMobileNumber("+"+copywith0)){
                                               // Log.d(TAG,"Phone: possible with after verification after vrified"+copywith0);
                                                //jsonArray.add(s);
                                                //phone.add(copywith0);
                                                phone.add(convertStandardJSONString(copywith0));
                                            }

                                        }

                                    }
                                }catch (NullPointerException e){}
                                catch (NumberParseException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
            i++;
        }
        phone=Objects.requireNonNull(phone);
        Log.d(TAG,"JSon:"+jsonArray.size());
        phone.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
        Set<String> hs = new HashSet<>();
        hs.addAll(phone);
        phone.clear();
        phone.addAll(hs);
        //Log.i(TAG, "NUmber of Contatcs: " + String.valueOf(i)+"\n"+"list size"+phone.size());
        for (int y=0;y<phone.size();y++){
          //  Log.d(TAG,"Array_list: "+phone.get(y)+"  json_list"+jsonArray.get(y)+"\n");
        }


    }


    return phone;
}
public static boolean isValidMobileNumber(String phone) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phone))
        return false;
    final PhoneNumberUtil phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
    try {
        Phonenumber.PhoneNumber phoneNumber = phoneNumberUtil.parse(phone, Locale.getDefault().getCountry());
        PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberType phoneNumberType = phoneNumberUtil.getNumberType(phoneNumber);
        return phoneNumberType == PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberType.MOBILE;
    } catch (final Exception e) {
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is the logcat result:

> ```
> Array size828
> 2018-12-14 07:30:37.432 25029-26960/com.example.root.boda D/Contact_TAG: Json Array to
> ```
>
> string["254741133082","254741133083","254741133084","254741133085","254724561852","254723682505","254772456998","254741133080","254741133081","254716550983","254700909017","254701389452","6785594462","6785594460","6785594461","254741133079","254708617549","254741133076","254741133077","254741133078","32468901349","254799302939","254710768069","32468901332","32468901330","6785594467","254704413355","254725967947","254719068000","6785594468","254701148467","6785594469","254705388507","254735730487","32468901336","32468901337","254707019734","254726044600","61404177647","6785594676","254710954360","23057911793","254725412223","254707485598","254728096111","37128909171","32468901368","254720671912","254729466494","254721808798","254721717621","6785999600","254716483828","254739497499","6785594451","254708753277","6785594450","254708617557","254722459845","254723235851","254741133042","254717109823","254723102063","254741133043","254741133044","254741133045","254741133041","61449015437","254728657128","254708345513","254713418008","6785594414","254726785139","254720610938","254702642030","254720700351","254723516105","254724284879","254724114910","254727102243","254727 456 557","32468901304","254755079071","254740117136","254755079072","254790624822","254791039378","254722619824","254740717332","254701499296","254704532914","254776992778","254792276498","254710978118","254790126098","254717898451","254704406898","254724030179","254791380500","32468901325","254737456860","254791845466","32468901323","254724467127","254720848120","254770888361","254714560079","254780945386","37255617788","254730124000","37123628890","254708489190","37123628892","37123628891","254714462609","254714229741","67570894108","32468901313","32468901314","254720893365","254724586752","254722931641","254701595752","254703656970","17672759447","254717668363","254714459498","254720601189","254790080382","254712651227","254702330880","254731725152","254720597028","93748502360","254725974637","254712192274","254725095347","254724239246","254731803976","967705210303","254717987521","254717521216","5493746288959","254706892333","61405284077","254701040949","254712045448","254709096000","254791369701","254733100111","254701639448","254713223971","254708824384","21698090036","254713787382","17672759451","254726115972","254709915000","25778675324","254729478260","254795082775","254703462246","254706615021","25778675321","254713657072","254722230305","254702744217","254703021000","254795713570","254703289327","254728086974","254727647973","254732282255","254707790892","254726256089","254720126752","254716100395","254710836007","254715406306","254718799745","254704358247","254720617963","254711523792","254792817272","254740460977","254714577345","254727073454","254707712615","254791042954","254796499114","254711429690","254706684678","254713105631","254737552981","254721138855","254711046999","254700093207","5493748502360","61414739233","254795155085","254727597083","254710809360","254710479200","254711218250","254716134905","61450735622","254706166227","254765199061","254711881085","254704986813","254701867730","254772254316","25729100928","41799775200","254717201134","32468931205","254716496588","254704628984","254724002456","41799775203","41799775202","41799775201","254720260881","61469350886","254700207664","254750100209","254750100208","254713244940","22569880964","254722427007","254700503258","254720223203","254721561357","254724333102","254701244396","254708851589","254710421253","254706313138","254755872755","254797508034","254790239559","254701145533","254726391889","254723042473","254708946935","254722293776","6768480002","254705317194","254780000348","61436025647","254711826273","254716551235","254790491413","254723491248","254751400262","254719316723","254721754455","254704099439","254786107568","254728678509","254715684243","41799775889","41799775888","41799775887","254716665372","254722896070","254792591160","254730692000","254707309337","254716460182","254714017442","254724636728","25470697967

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: any help  Rajen Raiyarela

Comment: Instead of `log` try to debug your code. Put a break point and then check the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, While printing the log messages in logcat,  If the length of message is more than 1000 characters, it gets broken. Means you won't able to print the full message and it will be broke at some point.

So, If logcat is capping the length at 1000 then you can split the string you want to log with String.subString() and log it in pieces. For example:

```
   public void logLargeString(String str) {
    if(str.length() > 3000) {
        Log.i(TAG, str.substring(0, 3000));
        logLargeString(str.substring(3000));
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, str); // continuation
    }
}
```

Now you can able to print all the contacts data (828 contacts, it might be more than 1000 chars) with out any breaks.  Then you can check the format of the output and parse the data accordingly.

Comment: thanx it has printed out the full string but your code didnt work had to use this

Comment: public void logLargeString(String str) {
        if(str.length() > 3000) {
            Log.i(TAG,"sub string"+ str.substring(0, 3000));
            logLargeString(str.substring(3000));
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG,"else logcat: "+ str); // continuation
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray myarray = new JSONArray();
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
     myarray.put( arrayList.get( i ).getContactNumber() );
}

JSONObject contactsObj = new JSONObject();
studentsObj.put("contacts ", myarray );
```

Comment: the problem steal persist